# Using final variables in anonymous threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, visibility

Is it safe to do something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  final int finalI = i;
  new Thread(() -> { 
       // use finalI in the thread somehow
       });
}
```

So the question I want to ask is, is it guaranteed that thread 0..9 will see finalI be 0..9 respectively?

For example what if in the second iteration finalI is changed and the first thread sees finalI to be 1 instead of 0.

I have a 99% feeling this is impossible, but I don't know how anonymous class store variables so I am not 100% sure.

If the anon class were to reference the outer reference to that variable then that would be wrong, but its not really a reference because its a primitive.. So how the heck does thread anon class store the variable?

Behind the scenes, does the JVM make it so that it gives a field private final int finalI in the anon thread and then set it in a constructor implictly?

Comment: It's captured and stored on the Runnable object. It can't change.

Comment: Sweet, but does the JVM implictly make a constructor for the Runnable under the hood?

Comment: It creates a field under the hood. I don't see what a constructor has to do with it.

Comment: Ah right, okay i guess it doesnt need a constructor since in a class you can do 

"final int finalI = someNum" instead of doing "final int finalI; and then set it in the constructor"

Comment: How can I accept a comment as an answer?

Comment: You can't... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finalI will be seen 0..9 respectively.

To understand what happens internally lets see what declaring a variable as

> final

does.

lets take

```
public class ThreadTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i =0; i< 9; i++) {
        final int finalI = i;
        new Thread(()->{
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000); // assuming a delay for some operations
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+finalI);
                //System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" "+ i); // can't do this.
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start(); 

    }
}
}
```

Local variables of the method are kept on the stack and lost as soon as the method ends. Whereas final variables/objects even declared locally can be accessible even after method ends given that they are referred by other classes/methods, in this case its runnable.

so when we execute

> final int finalI = i;

we are creating a new finalI variable and it can neither alter the previous one nor does the previous thread use this value as the earlier finalI's are put in JVM heap seperately.